# onMouseover not working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

I'm using `onmouseover` which works in my standard browser but does not seem to work in *Firefox*. I tried recreating it using *jQuery* but it still hasn't worked.

How could I make this compatible with *Firefox*?

```js
if (img_default.style.overflow != 'visible') {
    div.onmouseenter = function() {
      mouseOver(event)
    };
} else {
    el.style.display = "none";
}

function mouseOver(event) {
    if (img_default.style.overflow === 'visible') {
        el.style.display = "none";
    } else {
        el.style.display = "inline-block";
        var posX = event.offsetX ? (event.offsetX) : event.pageX - div.offsetLeft;
        var posY = event.offsetY ? (event.offsetY) : event.pageY - div.offsetTop;
        zoom.style.backgroundPosition = (-posX * 1) + "px " + (-posY * 1) + "px";
    }
}
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/f7g5dw4w/5/) is the entire JSFiddle.

Comment: Don't use `onXyz` event properties in the first place. That's a 25+ year old outdated technique. Use JQuery's `.on()` or vanilla `.addEventListener()` to set up event callbacks.

Comment: You appear to be trying to pass a non-existent `event`. `div.onmouseenter = mouseOver;` would be better, though even better, follow @Scott Marcus' advice.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is likely because you are losing the `event` object. In fact, I'm a bit surprised it's able to work in others.

Instead of having this:

```
div.onmouseenter = function() {
  mouseOver(event)
};
```

You need this:

```
div.onmouseenter = function(event) {
  mouseOver(event)
};
```

(Note the added `event`). Or better yet, just this:

```
div.onmouseenter = mouseOver;
```

Since it is already a function, no need to wrap them. Or, even better, avoid using `onmouseenter` and use `addEventListener()`:

```
div.addEventListener('mouseenter', mouseOver);
```

Comment: div.addEventListener('mouseenter', mouseOver);  this worked fine for chrome and firefox now as well. Thx. Unfortunately in IE11 it is only working partially now. The zoom box is shown but i the image shown is not moving when i move the cursor anymore.

Comment: Thanks for your help: it contributed in my answer!

Answer (score 0):

This would be the jQuery way.

- Converted everything to jQuery.
- Added scaling values for `x` and `y` for the zoom (`scaX` and `scaY`).

```js
/** jQuery plugin for reuse below. */
(function($) {
  $.fn.isOverflowVisible = function() {
    return this.css('overflow') === 'visible';
  };
  $.fn.setBackgroundPosition = function(pos) {
    return this.css({ backgroundPositionX : pos.x, backgroundPositionY : pos.y });
  }
})(jQuery);

var scale = { x: 0.71, y: 1.15 };
var imgsrc = $('#image').attr('src');
var $spot = $('#messages_product_view');
var $image = $('#image');
var $defaultImage = $('.product-image-zoom').first();
var $span = $('<span>', {
  id: 'zoom',
  css: { backgroundImage: 'url(' + imgsrc + ')' }
});
$spot.after($span);

if (!$defaultImage.isOverflowVisible()) {
  $image.on('mouseover', handleMouseOver)
        .on('mousemove', handleMouseOver)
        .on('mouseout', handleMouseOut);
} else $span.hide();

function handleMouseOver(e) {
  if ($defaultImage.isOverflowVisible()) $span.hide(); 
  else {
    $span.show();
    $('#zoom').setBackgroundPosition({
      x : (e.offsetX ? (e.offsetX * scale.x) : e.pageX - $span.offset().left) * -1,
      y : (e.offsetY ? (e.offsetY * scale.y) : e.pageY - $span.offset().top) * -1
    });
  }
}
function handleMouseOut(e) { $span.hide(); }
```

```css
#zoom {
  position: absolute;
  float: right;
  top: 10%;
  border: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  color: red;
  display: none;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);
      -ms-transform: scale(1.3);
       -o-transform: scale(1.3);
          transform: scale(1.3);
  z-index: 1000;
  left: 40%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="messages_product_view"></div>
<div class="product-img-box">
  <div class="ProductImageWrapper">
    <p class="product-image product-image-zoom" style="overflow: hidden; z-index: 9;">
      <img id="image" src="https://img-9gag-fun.9cache.com/photo/a47ZwBA_460s.jpg" style="width: 225px; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 0;"> </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I pasted in the jQuery but i get "Cannot read property 'first' of null" now.

Comment: That is because your `$('.product-image-zoom')` element is undefined. It's trying to grab the first element with the class name `product-image-zoom` in your document, but it does not exist for you.